# What is the easy way to get my wireless access point IP in OS Catalina

Tags: wifi, catalina, network

In the older versions of OSX it was possible to get your wireless AP IP address by pressing the option key and clicking the networking button on the top bar, they seem to of removed the AP IP from the displayed info since. What is the new on-the-fly method in the new OS Catalina?

Comment: In **Terminal**, the following _command_ will provide the information you're looking for, and a bit more too: `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType` If you just want the IP address of the Router, use: `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | grep 'Routers:'`

Comment: Would this be the quickest method of getting this info?

Comment: You can also get it from: **System Preferences** > **Network** > **Wi-Fi** > **Advanced…** > **TCP/IP**

Comment: The router is not necessarily the same device as the access point. It does not even have to have an IP address in the same subnet the router is.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- Click on topbar WIFI Icon -> Open Network Preferences and you can see IP Address below Status.
- Open terminal and put: `ifconfig | grep "inet "`

Comment: The OP is asking for the wireless access point IP address, which neither of your suggestions do, they give the IP address of the Mac.